# Where is my memory leak?

Tags: c

Can someone help me find my memory leak? Im using valgrind to check for leaks and I cant find the ones it is reporting. Thanks!

```
bigint* bi_create(const char* charint)
{

    int length = 0;
    const char* temp;
    int flag = 0;

    temp = charint;

   while(*charint != '\0')
    {

        length++;
        charint++;            
    }

    char chartoint[length];

    charint = temp;

    //printf("LENGTH = %d \n", length);

    bigint* bi = malloc(sizeof(bigint));

    bi->length = length; 

    int counter = 0;

    bi->initialzero = 0;

    while(*charint != '\0')
    {
        if(*charint == '0'  && flag != 1)
        {
            (bi->initialzero)++;
        }else
        {
            flag = 1;
        }

        chartoint[counter] = *charint;

      //  printf("CHARTOINT = %c \n", chartoint[counter]);
        charint++;
        counter++;

    }

    bi->data = atoi(chartoint);

    printf("DATA = %d \n", bi->data);
   // printf("INITIAL ZERO = %d \n", bi->initialzero);

    return bi;
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: The function could sure use some simplification. The first while loop can be replaced with `length=strlen(charint)`. In the second while loop, why are you copying into chartoint? Why not just do `bi->data=atoi(charint)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no memory leak in this function. However, if the memory allocated by this function is not freed by the caller, it will be leaked.

Comment: Thanks. I know I have to free the memory but I was having issues with my code.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your function there is **one malloc**:

```
bigint* bi = malloc(sizeof(bigint));
```

When you call this function :

```
bigint my_big_int = bi_create(my_string);
```

Don't forget to `free` it before leaving:

```
free(my_big_int);
```

That's it!